# Visual Studio leaves .cs file locked permanently after debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am experiencing an issue where every time I test my code, which is in a WPF project, the .cs source files are locked (which is expected) while the .xaml files are left unlocked, but after exiting debugging the .cs files never unlock - I cannot edit them post-debug. This question is not about why the files lock *during* debugging, but why I am having an issue with them staying permanently locked *after* debugging.

Details:

- The project is a WPF class library
- I have configured the project to start an external program which loads this library to debug. Breakpoints work fine, but none are set right now
- The project is under source control, but the file is checked out and **is not read-only**
- While the file is uneditable, it is not read-only
- Just My Code on/off does not affect this
- Closing out and reopening the file within Visual Studio results in the file being editable again
- The issue is very consistently reproducable, only on rare occasion does it not happen

Since I can close and reopen the tab to fix it, this isn't a massive problem, but losing my place in the code every single time is really quite annoying. I'm open to any suggested solutions.

Comment: I guess your starting of this external programme is at the root of the problem.

Comment: @Andy I would guess this too, but I'm at a loss for how to deal with it. When I don't debug by starting a program, it doesn't happen, but I mean, the files don't lock when not debugging so this is an obvious result. There's no other way I know of to debug a class library.

Comment: I usually add > existing project to add the class library to a solution with the exe project which will use it. You can then run the exe project and debug the class library project.

Comment: @Andy, I don't have the source for the exe project. This project is a plugin for a third party program.

Comment: Force it to close when you stop debugging.